# React Native importing function from exported class

Tags: react-native, import

I have a class in a file with the declaration:

```
export default class ParticipantRow extends Component
```

Within that class I have a function that I'd like to import in another class. 
Is there anyway I can import a single function from a class declared in the same way as my example, if so, how?

The function I wish to import has been bound to the ParticipantRow class' constructor. I wish to use this function as an eventhandler in another class, and if I simply declare ParticipantRow.handlePressParticipant() as an event handler in another class, after importing ParticipantRow, I get the following error: 'Undefined is not a function (evaluating '_ParticipantRow2.default.handlePressParticipant())'

In advance, thank you.

Comment: You can just import the whole class with `import ParticipantRow from './ParticipantRow.js';` and than run ParticipantRow.someMethod()

Comment: I migh not have been precise enough, I apologize if that's the case. 
The function I wish to import has been bound to the ParticipantRow class' constructor. I wish to use this function as an eventhandler in another class, and if I simply declare ParticipantRow.handlePressParticipant() as an event handler in another class, after importing ParticipantRow I get the following error: 'Undefined is not a function (evaluating '_ParticipantRow2.default.handlePressParticipant())'

Comment: If you want to use it as an event handler try to pass ParticipantRow.handlePressParticipant in without ()

It would be easier to understand if you provide code samples from both classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ParticipantRow is a react component defined using a class, I assume it has different methods and you would like to pass it to another component(we will call this OtherComponent) to be used as event handler. You could pass the member function of ParticipantRow to OtherComponent by using props.

```
class ParticipantRow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   // we need to bind this before we pass it to OtherComponent
   this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this); 
  }
  handleEvent(e) {
   // do something here
  }
  // In here we pass handleEvent to OtherComponent
  render() {
   return <OtherComponent handleEvent={this.handleEvent} />
  }
} 

class OtherComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }
  render() {
   return <button onPress={this.props.handleEvent} />
  }
}
```

Please take note that in this example OtherComponent is child of ParticipantRow therefore it is ok to pass method from parent(ParticipantRow) to child(OtherComponent), but if you have a different requirement let's say you would like to pass a method from ParticipantRow to another component which is not a child of this component, then you would have more work to do because in that case you would need to add an event system manually, or you might want to look at redux.

Further Reference
https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html